# How to instantiate multiple threads using the same function C++

Tags: c++, multithreading, multiple-instances

Here is function execute(), used for some instructions:

```
void execute() {

while (run) { //thread is running

    if (time % 3 == 0) { // execute instructions when clock is 3
        Instruct Instr;
        uint16_t src1 = 0;
        uint16_t src2 = 0;
        int target_cycle = time;
        while (target_cycle > time) {
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(thread_sleep);
        }

        while (hpp_DE_EX.size() != 0) {

            Instr = hpp_DE_EX.front();

            hpp_DE_EX.pop();

            uint16_t instr = Instr.header;

            ptrLog->PrintData(get, instr);

            src2 = instr & 0x1F;

            src1 = (instr >> 0x5) & 0x1F;

            uint16_t opcode = (instr >> 0xA) & 0x3F;   

            ....

      }


 //For running this thread:
 auto exThread = std::thread(&processor::execute, this);
 exThread.detach();
```

Using this function execute(), I want to create multiple instances of threads. I think this is a possibility to declare the threads (but when I am write this code I am getting some errors - INVOKE ERROR C2672) --- MODIFIED and now working

```
    std::vector<std::thread> threads;
    for (int i = 0; i <= 5; i++) // need 5 instances
    threads.push_back(thread(&processor::execute, this));

    cout << "Synchronizing all threads...\n";
    for (auto& th : threads) th.join();   // Running code
```

My intention is to use the execute() function (threads) to execute parallel instruction instead of linear instructions - functionable parameter.

Thanks, F.

Comment: I assume, that execute is not a static member function. Then you need to call it as `thread(&processor::execute, this, i))` or instead of `this` pass some `processor` instance

Comment: Please put the error in the question, and indicate the line of your code it refers you to.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming `processor::execute` is a static member function with no arguments then you are passing an extra argument to it so the `std::thread` implementation can't find an overload with the correct arguments. The correct invocation is:

```
threads.push_back(thread(&processor::execute));
```

or more simply:

```
threads.emplace_back(&processor::execute);
```

If it isn't a static method then you need to pass an instance of your processor class, e.g.:

```
processor p;
for (int i = 0; i <= 5; i++)
{
    threads.emplace_back(&processor::execute, &p);
}
```

Judging by printing `"Synchronizing all threads"` I think you don't understand what `std::thread::detach` does, it detaches the thread from the `std::thread` instance so that it can continue running once the structure is destroyed. I assume you actually meant to call `std::thread::join` which waits for the thread to finish executing. `std::thread::detach` is rarely the correct thing to do.

Comment: It is there any possibility to call the function execute() using parameters? E.g. execute0  for do an instruction set, execute1 another instruction set, execute2 .. And all this functions to be executed in parallel?

Comment: Yes, just append them to the end of the `std::thread` constructor